# Creating a JTable from AbstractTableModel in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, abstracttablemodel

I have this library that extends `AbstractTableModel` that I have to use to create a `JTable` in Netbeans:

```
package flickr;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * Modello di JTable basate su un ResultSet. <br> Si preferisce basare il
 * modello su un ResultSet, piuttosto che su una query, in modo da poter
 * condividerlo con il DBFrame.
 *
 * @author Massimo
 * @author ADeLuca
 */
public class DBTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private ResultSet rs; // Resultset su cui si basa il modello

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of DBTableModel.
     */
    public DBTableModel () {
        super ();
    }

    /**
     * Crea una nuova istanza di DBTableModel.
     *
     * @param r il ResultSet su cui basare il modello
     */
    public DBTableModel ( ResultSet r ) {
        super ();
        rs = r;
    }

    /**
     * Imposta il Resultset su cui si basa il modello.
     *
     * @param r il ResultSet su cui basare il modello
     */
    public void setRS ( ResultSet r ) {
        rs = r;
        fireTableStructureChanged ();

    }

    /**
     * Restituisce il nome di una colonna secondo i metadati del ResultSet.
     *
     * @param col intero, indice di colonna
     * @return stringa, il nome della colonna
     */
    @Override
    public String getColumnName ( int col ) {
        col++;
        if ( rs == null ) {
            return "";
        }
        try {
            return rs.getMetaData ().getColumnName ( col );
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            System.out.println ( e.getMessage () );
            return "";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Naviga il ResultSet per determinare il numero di righe.
     *
     * @return intero, numero di righe del modello
     */
    @Override
    public int getRowCount () {
        if ( rs == null ) {
            return 0;
        }
        try {
            int currentPosition, last;
            currentPosition = rs.getRow ();
            rs.last ();
            last = rs.getRow ();
            rs.absolute ( currentPosition );
            return last;
        } catch (/*
                 * SQL
                 */ Exception e ) {
            System.out.println ( e.getMessage () );
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determina il numero di colonne dai metadati del ResultSet
     *
     * @return intero, numero di colonne
     */
    @Override
    public int getColumnCount () {
        if ( rs == null ) {
            return 0;
        }
        try {
            return rs.getMetaData ().getColumnCount ();
        } catch (/*
                 * SQL
                 */ Exception e ) {
            System.out.println ( e.getMessage () );
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restituisce il valore da mostrare in una cella, in base al ResultSet
     *
     * @param row intero, indice di riga
     * @param col intero, indice di colonna
     * @return oggetto da mostrare nella cella (row,col)
     */
    @Override
    public Object getValueAt ( int row, int col ) {
        int currentPosition;
        Object ob;
        row++;
        col++;
        try {
            currentPosition = rs.getRow ();
            rs.absolute ( row );
            ob = rs.getObject ( col );
            rs.absolute ( currentPosition );
            return ob;
        } catch ( SQLException e ) {
            System.out.println ( e.getMessage () );
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Determina se una cella &egrave; modificabile. In questo modello si
     * &grave; scelto di non rendere direttamente modificabile nessuna cella.
     *
     * @param row intero, indice di riga della cella
     * @param col intero, indice di colonna della cella
     * @return sempre false
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable ( int row, int col ) {
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo di impostazione di un valore, ignorato a causa delle celle non
     * modificabili.
     *
     * @param value il valore da (non) impostare
     * @param row riga
     * @param col colonna
     */
    @Override
    public void setValueAt ( Object value, int row, int col ) {
        //rowData[row][col] = value;
        //fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
```

If I create the table manually, the object is correctly created, and I can get some test calls, like this:

```
Statement stmt;
String query = "SELECT SCREEN_NAME, EMAIL FROM USERS";
try {
    stmt = connection.getConnection ().createStatement ( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );
    ResultSet rset;
    rset = stmt.executeQuery ( query );
    DBTableModel dataModel = new DBTableModel ( rset );

    JTable jTable1 = new JTable ( dataModel );
    JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane ( jTable1 );

    //this call works fine
    System.out.println (jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(1, 1));


    stmt.close ();
    rset.close ();

} catch ( SQLException ex ) {
    Logger.getLogger ( TestQueryTable.class.getName () ).log ( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
}
```

But I can't get this table to get visible into the interface generated by NetBeans.

If I create a table using drag and drop into NetBeans interface, I don't know how to associate the built-in table and my code. What do I have to do?

Comment: Maybe you should add the scroll pane to something. If you are using the builder tool, I'd suggest dragging a table on to frame first, then just setting the model to _that_ table.

Comment: Just use `tableThatIDragged.setModel( dataModel );`, instead of creating a new table.

Comment: @peeskillet: yay, your solution works good! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "if i create a table using drag and drop into netbeans interface, i don't know how to associate the builtin table and my code."

Simple: `JTable` has a method [`setModel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setModel%28javax.swing.table.TableModel%29) that allows you to, well, set the model.

```
DBTableModel dataModel = new DBTableModel ( rset );
myDraggedTable.setModel( dataModel );
```

That's it.

Comment: 1+ There are also two alternatives using the visual editor: 1) Right-click over the table, select Table content option and use Custom code option to set a new DBTableModel() instance. 2) Right-click over the table, select Bind --> elements option, click on Import Data to Form and select a database connection. You won't need the custom table model anymore.

Comment: @dic19 Hmmm. Sounds like fun. Why don't you post that as answer :-)

Comment: It is indeed :-) Done. Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify I'd go with the method suggested by @peeskillet's first. But in addition I'd say you have two options using the visual editor (a.k.a: Matisse).

#### 1. Setting table content

Fist step, right-click over the table and select *Table Contents* option:

[image: Table Contents]

Select *Custom code* to set a new `DBTableModel()` instance as table model:

[image: Customizer Dialog]

#### 2. Using binding support to bind table content to a database connection

Right-click over the table and select *Bind → elements* option:

[image: Bind elements]

Click on *Import Data to Form* option and select both a database connection and a table to make the IDE generate the data binding for you. Note you won't need the custom model anymore.

[image: Import Data to Form]

Finally choose the desired fields to show in your table.

[image: Choose fields and press Ok]

**Note:** this option can also be done by selecting *Bound* option in Customizer Dialog shown in option 1.